# Which verb would fit better to describe the flow between the steps of a process?

Tags: word-choice

I'm describing the steps of a workflow and each step's description ends with the expression "Press the xxx button to ... to the next step". I can't decide which verb to use in this context. My alternatives are "go", "move", "jump", "pass". I'm leaning towards "go" and "move" but they sound to me like describing something physical. Which one would suit better in this context, any ideas?

Comment: Do you like the verb "proceed," for beginning or continuing a course of action, i.e., for doing something as a natural or seemingly inevitable next step?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was stuck here and you just rescued me :)

Comment: Continue? Carry on? Go on? Advance? There are plenty!

Comment: "Continue" could be a second alternative but @LittleEva 's solution fits better in this context. "Go on" is just another version of "go" which I don't prefer. "Advance" doesn't sound fitting.

Comment: The only one of your suggestions I don't like is *jump*. That seems to imply missing out something i.e. jumping over one stage and into the next. So I wouldn't say *jump to the next stage*.

Comment: 'Go on' is not just another version of 'go'; 'proceed' is much more a synonym of 'go on'. 'Move on' is often used for non-physical situations. 'Progress' is a simplex alternative if a MWV is considered too complex.

Comment: Wonder if you even *need* the verb there. A *for* in place of the *to* should work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the verb "proceed," for beginning or continuing a course of action, i.e., for doing something as a natural, inevitable, or otherwise appropriate ***next step***.

> **PROCEED** *intransitive verb*
>
> **1**: to come forth from a source:  issue; “*strange sounds proceeded from the room*”
>
> **2 a**: to continue after a pause or interruption **b**: to go on in an orderly regulated way
>
> **3 a**: to begin and carry on an action, process, or movement; **b**: to be in the process of being accomplished; “*the work is proceeding well*”
>
> **4**: to move along a course; to advance; see Merriam-Webster [**PROCEED**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proceed)

Answer (score 1):

You should **find what the professionals in this field are doing, not the general public**. In order to test that, search at Google Books (not vanilla/normal Google) for:

**"to proceed to the next step" user interface**
About 383 results

**"to go to the next step" user interface**
About 137 results

I would now select the version with "proceed," which even though more formal, is well accepted by the majority.

**Inserting the field-related "user" and "interface" in the search makes it to better select  publications related to this particular field.**

This is important, for in general the situation is reversed:

"to go to the next step"
About 191,000 results

"to proceed to the next step"
About 71,200 results